# Ontology constraint for linked individual

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl

I'm trying to specify a constraint in my ontology:
Let's say I have classes A, B and C and object properties "A hasB B" and "B hasC C". I would like to specify constraint that every individual 'a' of A is indirectly related to at least one of C, i.e. exists b,c that "a hasB b" and "b hasC c".

Is it possible to do this in OWL? If no, could you advice some technology that makes this sort of validation possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (in Turtle syntax):

```
:A  rdfs:subClassOf  [
    a  owl:Restriction;
    owl:onProperty  :hasB;
    owl:someValuesFrom  [
        a  owl:Restriction;
        owl:onProperty  :hasC;
        owl:someValuesFrom  :C
    ]
] .
```

I'm not very literate in Manchester syntax, but it must be something like:

```
A  subClassOf  (hasB  some  ( hasC  some  C ))
```

Again, as others have pointed out, the existence of a an individual does not mean that such individual is mentioned anywhere in the data.

Comment: Looks good! If that will not validate under CWA assumption, this is just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't out of the box use OWL as a constraint language as you appear to be attempting to do.  OWL has the [OWA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_world_assumption) (Open World Assumption) which makes expressing a constraint quite tricky.  There are system's, such as Pellet's [Integrity Constraints](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/icv), which let you use OWL as a constraint language by closing the world, altering slightly the semantics.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I understand that. As you've pointed out, I'm going to achieve CWA by using Pellet's property - works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Just use class equivalence:

```
A equivalentTo (hasB some B)
B equivalentTo (hasC some C)
```

This states that forall a in A exists b in B: a hasB b, and forall b in B exists c in C: b hasC c.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not exactly I want. The second line is not mandatory: there may exist some B without C, but there is at least one B for every A that has C. Please let me know if my case is not clear

Comment: what do you mean by mandatory? The second line says that b in B iff exists c in C: b hasC c. So clearly, every b must have some C. Note however that this does not have much consequence on open world reasoners. It merely leads them to rejecting any statement that EXPLICITLY denies any C to some B. I.e. the open world assumption means that just because a, b, and c are the only A, B, and Cs we know of, that does NOT mean that if a hasB b, then b hasC c, since there are infinitely many other As, Bs and Cs that we don't know about. As mentioned below, the OWA may be your actual problem.